# How to check if digital signature of signed document signed by trusted certificate?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I develop application which works with pdf documents and I've to understand that my document signed by trusted signature. 
I use itextsharp for getting information, but I don't how to check validity of signature.

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(document.FilePath);
var acroFields = pdfReader.AcroFields;
var names = acroFields.GetSignatureNames();

    foreach (var name in names)
    {
         var signatureName = name as string;
         var pk = acroFields.VerifySignature(signatureName);
         var signatureIsValid = false;
         foreach (var certificate in pk.Certificates)
         {
             signatureIsValid = certificate.IsValidNow; // It just check date
         }
    }
```

A document on the screen bellow has two digital signatures, but they signed without trusted certificate. I have to show some similar message for a user.

[image]

Comment: You check all of `pk.Certificates`. That is not necessary, a signature may bring along more certificates than required to build the signature chain. Thus, as @fatherOfWine in his answer indicates, select the signer certificate, built its chain and check that chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to check for trusted authority you need to have trusted CA certificate to check against. If you have one you could use code like this to check if cert came from trusted authority you are expecting it to be:

```
    X509Certificate2 authorityCert = GetAuthorityCertificate();
    X509Certificate2 certificateToCheck = GetYourCertificate();

    X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot;
    chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;
    chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = DateTime.Now;
    chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);

    //Adding your CA root to the chain
    chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(authorityCert);

    bool isChainValid = chain.Build(certificateToCheck);
    if (!isChainValid)
    {
        //Ok, let c what is wrong...
        string[] errors = chain.ChainStatus
            .Select(m => $"{m.StatusInformation.Trim()}, status: {m.Status}")
            .ToArray();

        string certificateErrors = "Error occured during checking certificate.";
        if (errors != null && errors.Length > 0)
            certificateErrors = string.Join(" \n", errors);

        throw new ApplicationException("Trust chain is not from known authority. Errors: " + certificateErrors);
    }

    //Let see if our chain actually contains known root, for which you are cheking
    if (!chain.ChainElements
        .Cast<X509ChainElement>()
        .Any(m => m.Certificate.Thumbprint == authorityCert.Thumbprint))
        throw new ApplicationException("Could not locate CA root!Thumbprints did not match.");
```